# fancybox - changing close button color

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox

I did download fancybox and I'm trying to change the color of the close button.

I did try without any result:

```
.fancybox-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: -18px;
  right: -18px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 8040;
  color : #ff0033 !important; //color added
}
```

Any tip will be appreciated.

Comment: By default, Fancybox uses image sprite as its close button. Basically it's a image.

Comment: I know Rock. I did change it to red in photoshop but it's still black.

Comment: It's very weird to me. It's still displaying the old image. I did check in the image folder, and the image is the new one. I did check the URL and it's correct. I did close the browser to refresh the cache. No way. There still the image. I did check by searching the whole site folder and, nothing, there are not duplicated images.

Comment: Try to add this in the image URL `?version=2` e.g. `image.png?version=2`. Please add your html `<head>` in the question.

Comment: It worked!  ?version=3. Many thanks Rock!!! Could you add the solution to your main answer pleae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cache issue. In order to fix this, try to add `?version=2` in image URL.

Usage:

`background: transparent url('image.png?version=2') -40px 0px`

Answer (score 0):

You can install firebug firefox add-on and right click on the close button --> Inspect Eliment with Firebug. Then you can find the css name.

You can edit jquery.fancybox.x.x.x.css

or you can add below code to your page css.

```
.fancybox-close {
 background: none !important; //This will disappear close button image
 position: absolute !important;
 top: -18px !important;
 right: -18px !important;
 width: 36px !important;
 height: 36px !important;
 cursor: pointer !important;
 z-index: 8040 !important;
 color : #ff0033 !important; //color added
}
```

Comment: Yep, I have done that before. I'm edditing the main fancybox css file.

Comment: As I figured out [this is the image](http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox.png)

Comment: The path is the correct one. It's pointing to the folder "img" and the image "fancybox_sprite.png". Checking with the inspector, the url shows the old image that doesn´t exist. It was changed in Photoshop. I did clean the cache, shutdown the browser... Nothing changes the result. There are not duplicates of the image in the whole site.

Comment: RockMyAlgorithm did add the correct solution. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It is because of your image already saved in cache. Thats why It will not change to new one.

Answer (score -2):

As said before, fancybox uses an image by default. This one 'http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/fancy_close.png'

You can find it in the file `jquery-fancybox-x.x.x.css` 
 (where x is the version), and the element is named **#fancybox-close**

Comment: Broke link to image. I'm just editing the file you pointed at. #fancybox-close doesn´t exist but .fancybox-close

Comment: I'm right now changing the icon doing what I've said. The link is not broken, you can access and see how the image looks like. Just change the **background** property

Comment: The link points me to a "Forbidden" message. Anyway, RockMyAlgorithm has the right solution. Many thanks for your help.